# adding onclicklistener to recycler view with viewbinding, kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewbinding

Trying to add an onclicklistener to the items in my recycler view, that will use an intent to open another activity. I've tried finding examples, but I can only find examples using Java or Kotlin examples that aren't using viewbinding.

```
package com.truuce.anotherrvtest

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager

import com.truuce.anotherrvtest.databinding.ActivityHeroBinding

class HeroActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var binding: ActivityHeroBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHeroBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)

        val adapter = CardAdapter(HeroList.heroList)
        binding?.heroRV?.adapter = adapter
        binding?.heroRV?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 3)

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        binding = null
    }
}
```

```
package com.truuce.anotherrvtest

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.truuce.anotherrvtest.databinding.HeroCardBinding

class CardAdapter(val heroList: List<Hero>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.MainViewHolder>() {

    inner class MainViewHolder(val heroBinding: HeroCardBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(heroBinding.root) { 
        fun bindHero(hero: Hero){
            heroBinding.heroNameTV.text = hero.heroName
            heroBinding.heroIV.setImageResource(hero.image)
        }

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainViewHolder {


        return MainViewHolder(HeroCardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val hero = heroList[position]
        holder.bindHero(hero)
    }


    override fun getItemCount() = heroList.size
}
```

tried adding View.OnClickListener to MainViewHolder, then implemented a member. OnClick(p0: View){}, but no idea how to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a functional property for a click listener in your adapter.

The Activity can set the item click listener behavior.

```
class CardAdapter(
    val heroList: List<Hero>,
    val itemClickListener: (Hero)->Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.MainViewHolder>() {

    inner class MainViewHolder(val heroBinding: HeroCardBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(heroBinding.root) { 
        fun bindHero(hero: Hero) = with(heroBinding) {
            heroNameTV.text = hero.heroName
            heroIV.setImageResource(hero.image)
            root.setOnClickListener { itemClickListener(hero) }
        }

    }

    //...
}
```

```
// In Activity:

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHeroBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)

        val adapter = CardAdapter(HeroList.heroList) { hero ->
            // do something with hero item when it's clicked
        }
        binding?.heroRV?.adapter = adapter
        binding?.heroRV?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 3)

    }
```

Comment: By the way, there's no reason to make your binding nullable and null it out in an Activity. That's only for Fragments. It's unnecessary in an Activity since they are destroyed permanently once `onDestroy` is reached anyway. So you can make it a `lateinit var` and not have to use the `?`s or override onDestroy.